# Regular replace explression

Tags: regex

Subject text:

```
$types[CNT_ANONS] = t('Announcement', 'content_type');
```

I need some find and replace expression in order to get result:

```
$types[CNT_ANONS] = Yii::t('content_type', 'Announcement');
```

So, "t" replaced with "Yii::t" and arguments of function should be vice versa.

Note: The expressions should be in "perl" syntax (I use it within sublime text editor). And be awere that "Yii::t" might be occured in subject text.

Comment: Can you show [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) so far and why it didn't work?

Comment: Can you specify what language are you using?

Comment: find: " t\(('\w+'),\s('\w+')"

Comment: replace: " Yii::t(\2, \1"
that is working but there is some problems with that (I in the strings could be not only words)

Comment: m0skit0, code is written on PHP (Yii framework), I am trying to replace it with Sublime text editor (which is required perl syntax)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try

```
Search : t\('([^']+)',\s'([^']+)'\);
Replace: Yii::t('\2', '\1');
```

Comment: Thank you, it is pretty close to mine one, but what is in text will be that: t('update {lang} version', 'form_model', array('{lang}' => $rec->lang))
How to say "anything" within strings, the goal is just replace them vice versa

Comment: I updated my answer. We look anything but ' until next '

Comment: Briliant! That is what I was looking for, but last issue is left. In order not to match "Yii::t" we placed first space, but it could be absent: $email->message =t('Your new password', 'user').
In other words next items should not be matched:
$this->guestName = Yii::t('user', 'Guest');
subject('string1', 'string2');

Answer (score -1):

Try:

> ```
>  $data = '$types[CNT_ANONS] = t(\'Announcement\', \'content_type\');';
>  $res = preg_replace('@\$([^\s]+?)(\s+?)=(\s+?)t\((\'|")(.+?)(\'|"),(\s*?)(\'|")(.+?)(\'|")(.*?)\);@sim', "\$$1$2=$3Yii::t($8$9$10, $4$5$6$11);", $data);
>  //                    ^_______________^----finding var
>  //                                               ^________________^----first argument    
>  //                                                                       ^________________^----second argument
> ```

Comment: I'm update solution with compatibilities of third and the next arguments

Comment: works perfectly with `$data = '$types[CNT_ANONS] = t(\'update {lang} version\', \'form_model\', array(\'{lang}\' => $rec->lang));';`